# Regarding std::list, if I want to sort in descending order can I simply call "mylist.sort(>)"?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

Assuming that whatever objects the list holds implements a proper `>` operator.

Comment: use `std::less`/`std::greater`

Comment: @BryanChen as in literally type "mylist.sort(std::greater)"?

Answer (score 4):

Use  :

`mylist.sort(std::greater<T>());`

T is type of container elements. eg. `int`, `char`, `float`, etc.

For T as objects you need to overload `operator '>'` or define your own comparator function

```
bool cmp(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{

  //compare criteria 
}
```

And then,

`mylist.sort(cmp);`

Comment: `std::greater` will also work for objects if they have an `operator>`

Comment: @Blastfurnace So if my object T implements operator> then I can just call "mylist.sort(std::greater<MYOBJECT>());"?

Comment: @MilanNovaković: Yes, assuming MYOBJECT is the type name.